# Spring boot how make a user role managing with jwt

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, roles

I'm writing a RESTful api with spring boot.
I'm using spring boot, jersey, mongo db, swagger, spring boot security and jwt.

I have written the models, the repositories for the requests to the DB. Now I have integrated the Security and jwt token.

Now I need to discretize the role of the users, because a user cant call a route that need an admin priviledges.

I have a route for login, it's return a token. This is the code of my SecurityConfig

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/swagger.json").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/*").authenticated()
                .and()

                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager(), userRepository),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

I written the JWTLoginFilter that return me the token when user makes login

```
...
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    Credential creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), Credential.class);

    User user = userRepository.login(creds);

    if (user == null)
        throw new BadCredentialsException("");

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        creds.getUsername(),
        creds.getPassword()
    );

    return token;
}
...
```

I want insert this on my endpoint class on method

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

this is a part of an endpoint

```
....

@Component
@Path("story")
@Api(value = "Story", produces = "application/json")
public class StoryEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StoryEndpoint.class);

    @Autowired
    StoryRepository storyRepository;


    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") <--- I want insert here
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get All Story", response = Story.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "hello resource found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Given admin user not found")
    })
    public Response getAllStory(){
        Iterable<Story> stories = storyRepository.findAll();
        LOGGER.info("getAllStory");
        return (stories!=null) ? Response.ok(stories).build() : Response.ok(ResponseErrorGenerator.generate(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)).status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
....
```

How I can make a mechanism for assign to user the role and how i can pass the role in token and discretize on route the role of user?

Comment: Don't mix authorities and roles (which are authorities with the "ROLE_" prefix), use either `hasRole('ADMIN')` or `hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')`.

Answer (score 13):

You need to store user roles inside JWT token as additional claims, extract them after token validation and pass as 'authorities' for principal:

```
 Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
                = Arrays.asList(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(",")).stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "",
                authorities);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken t
                = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "", authorities);
```

Comment: I need to modify my User class? I haven't understood the first part of code. 
Where I insert this piece of code? @Alex Chemyshev

Comment: First part of code is about extraction list of role names, separated by ','. You should put this code instead of ' UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        creds.getUsername(),
        creds.getPassword()
    );'

Comment: but you will need also to add list of roles into JWT token, otherwise it  will not work. Maybe full solution with Spring & JWT auth will help you better: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-token/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/UserJWTController.java

Comment: I tried to change the code but it does not work and I do not receive errors. I cannot understand where I'm wrong. https://gist.github.com/paranoiasystem/83cc4cae0235a54b2c778145f28b2aa5

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paranoiasystem/83cc4cae0235a54b2c778145f28b2aa5#file-jwtloginfilter-java-L55 you need to put login instead of whole object here

Comment: I tried to put user.getEmail() but not change. what do you mean for login?

Comment: your 'User' class implements UserDetails, so getUsername() method will be used to get login

Comment: I tried but not work, username and email is equal, 
I do not know what changes since they have the same value.

Answer (score 6):

First need to add the roles inside the JWT. For that you can add as Claim in the JWT Generator class.

```
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> Userroles = new HashSet<>();
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        for(Role role:user.getRoles()){
            Userroles.add(role.getName());
        }
        claims.put("Roles",Userroles.toArray());
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }
```

In the user model class need to include the roles in Set or any other data structure.

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

In the Repository need to have a method like below.

```
User findByUsername(String username);
```

Please check this Github Repo(https://github.com/Senthuran100/SpringBoot_JWT) for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

you should add role into Token and for example you can refer following link:-
http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/