# How to add roles to Spring Boot security from a Zuul filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, netflix-zuul

I am developing a Spring Boot REST application that has a custom token authentication system. The token holds the roles for the user as claims.

A Zuul proxy routes the traffic to multiple spring boot microservices and I would like to add a filter to the Zuul so that it extracts the roles from the token (stored as claims) and sets them in the Spring security environment (which I don't know the internals) so that I can configure the access in the micro services using the standard Spring security approach, using for example a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("secret1")
                .roles("USER").and().withUser("admin1").password("secret1")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
```

So, to rephrase... how can I include those roles from my custom token using a pre-filter in Zuul so they are part of the AuthenticationManagerBuilder object?

Comment: Your understanding is off. You don't put then in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as that is a one time instantiated object. Just pass the token and configure JWT properly for your services.

Comment: Well, thanks for your comment but I think I didn't explain properly my request. I am using a custom token with specific claims. I cannot reconfigure or change it. How can I make Spring Security in my services work with those roles? AuthenticationManagerBuilder is just an example, probably wrong. I am asking where in the code can I inject in the request the roles so that Spring security processes them.

Comment: My problem is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253707/spring-boot-how-make-a-user-role-managing-with-jwt

Comment: According to this problem... how can I "pass my roles as 'authorities' for principal"?

Comment: Just extract them and add them to the `Authentication` object. The token contains the principal with the roles.

Comment: Thanks. What type of Authentication should I use? I guess not UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken as it is already authenticated and I don't have the password, just the roles. Also... I do that in attemptAuthentication() method and just return the generated token?

Comment: If you are already authenticated why would you need the password... Just create a new `Authentication` with the extracted roles. But if it is JWT why not simply use the default JWT support?