# Convert set to claim in jwt java

Tags: json, jackson, set, jwt

I have a `set<Authority>` I set this `set<Authority>` in .claim and I override toString in Authority, for return the attribute name.

```
set<Authority> authorities;
Jwts.builder().claim("Authorities",authorities.toString());
```

I get this json: `"[ADMIN,USER]"`
and I need this: `["ADMIN","USER"]`

How can I map this set in the correct way? I can use anyanotathion in Authority class

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43254958/1815727) answer.

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
                = Arrays.asList(claims.get(YOUR_AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(",")).stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```